# How to combine two tables with different dates and join on other table?

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I am currently trying to perform a query with Laravel / Eloquent but I decided to write the SQL query first in order to figure out what the problem is.
I want to group by dates and combine the results of two tables using multiple joins but the results get wrong when I add the `product_metrics` table like this:

```
inner join `product_metrics` on `products`.`id` = `product_metrics`.`product_id`
```

[image: Database Schema]

```
select
  date_format(`date` + INTERVAL 1 HOUR, '%Y-%m-%d') as day,
  round(sum(`item_price` * `quantity_ordered`), 2) as sales,
  sum(`quantity_ordered`) as units,
  sum(
    CASE
      WHEN `is_refund` THEN `item_price` * `quantity_ordered`
      ELSE 0
    END
  ) as refunds,
  sum(
    CASE
      WHEN `is_refund` THEN `quantity_ordered`
      ELSE 0
    END
  ) as refund_units,
  sum(`promotion_discount`) as discounts,
  sum(`sessions`) as sessions,
  count(DISTINCT(customer_order_id)) as orders,
  round(sum(`product_sales`), 2) as sales_sc,
  round(
    sum(`unit_session_percentage` * `product_sales`) / sum(`product_sales`),
    2
  ) as cvr,
  sum(`page_views`) as views

from
  `products`
  inner join `product_brands` on `products`.`brand_id` = `product_brands`.`id`
  inner join `customer_order_items` on `products`.`id` = `customer_order_items`.`product_id`
  inner join `customer_orders` on `customer_order_items`.`customer_order_id` = `customer_orders`.`id`
  inner join `product_metrics` on `products`.`id` = `product_metrics`.`product_id`
  inner join `customers` on `products`.`customer_id` = `customers`.`id`
  inner join `marketplaces` on `products`.`marketplace_id` = `marketplaces`.`id`
  where
  (
    `date` between "2019-05-01 00:00:00"
    and "2019-05-31 00:00:00"
    or `purchase_date` between "2019-05-01 00:00:00"
    and "2019-05-31 00:00:00"
    and `customers`.`id` = 18
  )
  and `products`.`deleted_at` is null
group by
  date_format(`date` + INTERVAL 1 HOUR, '%Y-%m-%d')
order by
  `day` asc
```

What I want / need to do is:
Query for `products` with a where clause and also add dates to get all `product_metrics` and all `customer_orders` related to those products in the given period of time.

Comment: Show us db schema, sample data, current and expected output. 
 Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

 [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

 Try create a sample in http://rextester.com

Comment: Post the tables and data as text [READ THIS](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: Without data or desire output we don't know what is wrong. My suggestions is simplify your problem to `SELECT * FROM Products` and then start adding tables one by one. But I think you can't join `marketplace` and `product_metrics` at the same time as `customers`. That is why you got so many rows. You will see that when changing your query to just `SELECT *`

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean...

```
              date between "2019-05-01 00:00:00" and "2019-05-31 00:00:00"
or ( purchase_date between "2019-05-01 00:00:00" and "2019-05-31 00:00:00"
 and customers.id = 18)
```

?

Also, it's much easier to follow if you alias your tables, and qualify your columns with those aliases.

Comment: If that were the case, the parenthesis arent need it, I think is the other way around

Comment: Thanks for your approach, I answered in below Juans answer

Answer (score 0):

My guess is you missing the parenthesis to make sure the OR is handle first.

```
A or B and C ==> A or ( B and C )
```

You probably want

```
( A or B ) and C
```

So

```
where
(
  (    `date` between "2019-05-01 00:00:00" and "2019-05-31 00:00:00"
    or `purchase_date` between "2019-05-01 00:00:00" and "2019-05-31 00:00:00"
  )
  and `customers`.`id` = 18
)
```

Comment: @Strawberry and Juan, either way my results for `sales (customer_orders table)` increase for example from (700 to 80k) just from joining the `product_metrics` table

Answer (score 0):

Considering the one to many relationship between products and metrics this is as expected.